# Adding a Line Separator between two TextViews in Android XML

Tags: android, xml

Recently I started practicing Android Development and I am stuck at a very basic problem. Since I am a beginner in this field, I am asking for your help.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="Name1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"

           />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Name2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"

        />
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/player_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"
        />




</LinearLayout>
```

In this XML scheme, I am trying to put a text followed by text-space and repeating it again. 
e.g.     Name1 ___________________ //Next Line//
         Name2 ___________________

But the problem is that Name2 is not going into the next line and staying in the same line . 
Please tell me how to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In these type of scenarios I create a layout within a layout.

So each line of yours will be a layout and hence. You can only those elements in that line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left" >

    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add orientation = vertical and I've changed your widths to match parent.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name1" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="18sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player_name1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name2" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="18sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/player_name2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/abc_max_action_buttons"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Not sure exactly what height space you want, but have used your dimensions.

[image: view]